# Can a Category Entry have an Author

Tags: categories

This may be basic but not finding the right way to do it so here is a question.
I have a category page where each has its own url and have custom fields on it. But for some reason the author is not showing on the right side like the entries do?

Is there a reason categories dont have authors or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Categories do not have authors. They should not be considered "content" like entries in channels or structures, but as a way to relate entries or assets together. If you needed to associate a category with a particular person, you can create a user field and add it to the categories custom fields.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, `categories` do not support authors. And I would guess that it was just a best-use-case decision in the design of craft; generally categories would be to used to organize entries independent of author. If you need author support, then I would suggest using a structure or channel, which in most other respects can serve the same purpose and be used in the same way.